# exceljs way to import file and see connection string

Tags: javascript, excel, sqlconnection, exceljs

I'm working to create an application that replaces a series of excel files. From looking at exceljs it is easy to import an xlsx file and see some of the workbook properties but I need to save all the connection strings (data > queries & connections > connection properties > connection string and command text (query)).

```
const ExcelJS = require('exceljs');

var workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook(); 
workbook.xlsx.readFile('a.xlsx')
    .then(function() {
        console.log('Workbook properties')
        console.log(workbook.getWorksheet(9))
    });
```

this is where I would go to see the sql database connection in excel:
[sql connection setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goWi5.png)

Comment: I don't understand this  your statement meaning `connection strings (data > queries & connections > connection properties > connection string and command text (query))` can you show the example with image?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.